# Working out total from sub total and amount

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table with purchased orders data.
Each row contails the amount of certain item purchased, cost per item and the order number group.  Each different item purchased is a new row with same order number.

I basically want to return the total cost for that order. I have tried the following but am getting nowhere:

```
SELECT order_number, SUM( sub_total ) AS `total`
FROM
  SELECT order_number, SUM( SUM( amount ) * SUM( cost_per_item ) ) AS `sub_total`
    FROM `ecom_orders`
   WHERE member_id = '4'
GROUP BY order_number
ORDER BY purchase_date DESC
```

Comment: For what database?  If you get errors, it helps to let us know what those might be ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much any SQL-92 compliant RDBMS will take this:

```
SELECT
order_number
,SUM(amount * cost_per_item) AS total
,purchase_date
FROM
ecom_orders
WHERE member_id = '4'
GROUP BY order_number,purchase_date
ORDER BY purchase_date DESC
```

Comment: if there will be different purchase date for each item and same order number then I think your query will give wrong total.

Comment: Absolutly on the money! perfect.

Comment: Then leave the purchase_date out of the `SELECT`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`

Comment: Can I ask why (just so I know)

Comment: It's the difference between aggregating the total by order_number alone or `order_number` and `purchase_date`. Now that I think about it, most orders are filled at the same time so `purchase_date` is kind of superfluous.